# Folder getParents fails to get Team Drive name in Google Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-drive-shared-drive

I'm trying to build up the full path to a document in a team drive using a script.  The code looks like this:

```
var path = [ ]
var folder = id.getParents()
while (folder && folder.hasNext()) {
  var f = folder.next()
  path.unshift(f.getName())
  folder = f.getParents()
}
```

This script is bound to a document for testing.

But when I get to the root, instead of returning the actual name of the Team Drive, such as "Accounting" or "Marketing" it instead returns "Team Drive".  I need to know the actual *name* of the Team Drive, why am I not getting this info?  If I run this in a script bound to a document in My Drive, it instead says "My Drive" at the root - this at least makes sense, because that's the actual name I see in the browser.  In Team Drive, the root is actually "Team Drives" not "Team Drive".

Comment: `DriveApp` is not 100% integrated with Team Drives... use the Drive advanced service (i.e. the Drive REST API, v2) to get the Team Drive resource by id. When you reach the root, where `f.getName()` is "Team Drive", what is the previous folder's name?

Comment: @tehhowch The previous folder's name is the top-level folder under the Team Drive in question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because Team Drives are implemented differently than "regular" Google Drive "folders", the built-in `DriveApp` is not guaranteed to work properly for all actions that deal with them. It is possible that at some point `DriveApp` will be updated to fully support Team Drives, but there are a lot of sensible things that Google still has yet to do ;)

Instead, use the "advanced service" `Drive`, which is a client application that implements version 2 of the Drive REST API, and allows properly handling Team Drive information. As an "advanced service", you **must** [enable this service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enabling_advanced_services) before you can use it.

To build the full path of a Team Drive item using only the advanced service:

```
function getTeamDrivePath(fileId) {
  // Declare we know how to handle Team Drive items, and that they be included in responses.
  var params = {
    supportsTeamDrives: true,
    includeTeamDriveItems: true
  };
  // Return only the fields we want, instead of the whole `File` resource.
  params.fields = "id,title,parents/id"

  // In a Team Drive, a file can have only one parent folder (e.g. "normal" filesystems).
  // (parent.isRoot is never true for Team Drive folders so it is not used.)
  var path = [], file;
  do {
    file = Drive.Files.get(fileId, params);
    path.unshift(file.title);
    fileId = file.parents.length ? file.parents[0].id : null;
  } while (fileId);

  // Since we also added the file, the last element of the path array is the filename.
  path.pop();

  // A Team Drive is subject to different permissions than files, and thus its name must be 
  // obtained via the Team Drives resource. Since `file` points to the Team Drive, use it:
  // Requesting incorrect fields will result in an API error, so request the proper ones:
  params.fields = "name"
  var td = Drive.Teamdrives.get(file.id, params);
  path[0] = td.name;
  return path;
}
```

More reading about Team Drives and handling associated with them is available on the Drive REST API reference. I link the v2 versions since they are what is available via Apps Script's "Advanced Service", but the v3 version should be used for 3rd party applications using the client libraries.

Important resources:

- [About Team Drives](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/web/about-teamdrives)
- [Enabling Team Drives support](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/web/enable-teamdrives)
- [Team Drives API Reference](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/teamdrives)
- [Enabling "Advanced Services" in Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enabling_advanced_services)
- [API Best Practices: Partial Resources & "fields"](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/performance#partial)

Comment: To be clear, is the advanced service available from app scripts? 
 I'm getting `ReferenceError: "Drive" is not defined`.  I must be missing something here...

Comment: @I'-'I That fixed that, but while it recognizes Drive.Files, it says Drive.TeamDrives is undefined...

Comment: `Drive.TeamDrives should be Drive.Teamdrives`

Comment: I've made an edit to add what was missing to get this to work for me

Comment: Hi Michael, I am getting a `TypeError: Cannot read property "length" from undefined.` when trying to use this script - do you know if anything has changed since the time of writing?

Comment: @SL8t7 the only place `length` is used is on the `parents` attribute of the resource returned by [`Drive.Files.get()`](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/get), which is a [`File`](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files). Per the API spec, unless you are supplying the `fields` option in the optional parameters, that attribute should be present. For the purposes of this snippet, one could probably add it, as that's all that is being used. I've just re-run it on a test drive and it works without issue.