# Possible to move files from teamdrive to gdrive using google script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-shared-drive

I am the owner of a team drive and my own google drive.

I would like to move a certain folder from my team drive to google drive on a weekly schedule.

Is this possible to do using google script app?

I didn't see any team drive or move functionality when I reviewed the API, so I am assuming it is not possible.

Comment: This question does not show research effort. You should review [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @StefanCrain I reviewed the api documentation for google-apps-scripts and did not see  any API for this, and I just want to confirm this is the case.  What other research would you like me to provide?

Comment: Of course. But you'll have to use the Drive Advanced Service, which implements the Drive REST API (v2). I show how Team Drives can be accessed in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49544034/9337071
There are many other existing SO questions about Team Drives, like this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48213373/accessing-files-and-folders-in-team-drive so doing research on `google-drive-sdk` may be helpful

Comment: Thanks @tehhowch.  Does running the Drive Advanced Service count against your hourly API limitation? The main thing drawing me to google-apps-service is that it doesn't count against your hourly api limitation, which I am always pushing, I want to confirm Drive REST API doesn't count against it as well, if using google-apps-script

Comment: Any usage of Google services consumes some quota, apps script is no different. Using the native `DriveApp` has a quota, just like the Drive REST API.